# Toggling symmetrical input to asymmetrical

Tags: usability, gui-design

At the moment I'm working on a project where the input was always symmetrical. Symmetrical meaning that the right side is always the same as the left side.

Now we got another requirement, that the left side in can vary from the right side and this only in some cases.

To illustrate the Problem I've done some Balsamiq Wireframes. In every solution that i found so far there is a flaw. And i just don't find a solution that is simple for the user to understand and doesn't feel hectic on the UI.

Is there any suggestion how to handle this situation?

**Symmetrical:**

[image: Symmetrical Input]

**Asymmetrical Problem With Left/Right and Both**

[image: Asymmetrical Problem With Left/Right and Both]

**Solution 1: With labels**

[image: Solution 1: With labels]

**Solution 2: Wide input**

[image: Solution 2: Wide input]

**Solution 3: Shifting to center**

[image: Solution 3: Shifting to center]

Comment: Do inputs on the left refer to left values and on the right to right values? For example, in your Solution 2, the Diameter input occupying both sides means  there is only one diameter without side, a diameter that has both sides or a diameter only on the right side?

Comment: Yes if the toggle for "Left/Right side identical" is off, then it means that if there are two input fields one is for left and one is for right. If there is only one, it means that left and right are still identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using two columns or any resemblance between left/right physical values and left/right positioned inputs. You could think of the toggle as selecting between one common value or two values (where applicable). Also the toggle button reinforced some kind of relation between the side it is toggled to and the column on that side, when it is not the case.

[image: one column]

Comment: Thank you. This is actually just the easiest solution to the problem. The reason i came up with the left right input being left or right is because there are other parts of the Software where the whole form is asymmetrical. I was probably just to blind to see the obvious solution to this :)

Comment: I'm glad it could help :)